# Swift - how do I make the textfield recognize more than one correct answer in quiz?

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a quiz and there are multiple correct answers to the question. For example in the below code the correct answer is "pink" to the question of "what is the colour of the lesion(s)". But I also want it to recognize that red will also be counted as a correct answer. Is there a way of coding multiple correct answers for a question? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import Foundation

import UIKit

class Case1Q2ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var imageButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var questionLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var correctAnswerLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var inputTextField: UITextField!

var enteredAnswer: String?

var correctAnswers = ["Pink", "Red"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(Case1Q2ViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(Case1Q2ViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

    inputTextField.delegate = self

    titlesForLabels()
    nextButton.enabled = false

    imageButton.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
    imageButton.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    imageButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

    questionLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
    questionLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    questionLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func titlesForLabels() {
    questionLabel.text = "What is the colour of the lesion(s)?"
    correctAnswerLabel.text = correctAnswers.joinWithSeparator(", ")
    correctAnswerLabel.hidden = true

    inputTextField.text = nil
    inputTextField.enabled = true
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

    let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardFrame.size.height
    })
}

func keyboardWillHide() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    })
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    enteredAnswer = textField.text

    checkForCorrectAnswer()

    return true
}

func checkForCorrectAnswer() {
    let answer = enteredAnswer!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
    if correctAnswers.contains(answer.lowercaseString) {
        print("Correct")
        correctAnswerLabel.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        correctAnswerLabel.text = "Correct!"
        nextButton.enabled = true

    } else {
        print("Wrong Answer")
        correctAnswerLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        correctAnswerLabel.text = "Incorrect! Please try again"
        nextButton.enabled = false

    }
    correctAnswerLabel.hidden = false
}
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    navigationItem.title = "Case 1: Q2"
}
```

}

Comment: Make `correctAnswer` an array of all the acceptable answers and check if `correctAnswer.contains(enteredAnswer)`

Comment: @dan, I am new to coding and swift. Is there any way you can show me that in my code?

Comment: @Babz: Welcome to StackOverflow, Programming and Swift! If I may offer one advice, it would be to have a go at implementing a solution yourself before asking someone to write it for you (especially easy ones). Apple's Playground makes this particularly easy because you can see the output of your code in real time. Good Luck and hope you make a killer app :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep an array of correct answers by replacing your `var correctAnswer = "Pink"` line with `var correctAnswers = ["pink", "red"]`

Then, in your `checkForCorrectAnswer()` method, you have to check if the array of correct answers contains the answer that was entered:

```
func checkForCorrectAnswer() {
    let answer = enteredAnswer!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
    if correctAnswers.contains(answer.lowercaseString) {
        // Correct
    } else {
        // Incorrect
    }
}
```

Comment: I just get an error (Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String')  in this line when I do that 
 
`func titlesForLabels() {

    questionLabel.text = "What is the colour of the lesion(s)?"
        **correctAnswerLabel.text = correctAnswers**
        correctAnswerLabel.hidden = true`

Any recommendations of how to get around this?

Comment: That would depend on how you want the label to look.  You could do `correctAnswerLabel.text = correctAnswers.joinWithSeparator(", ")`

Comment: I did what you suggested and edited my code above to reflect the changes you recommended. However, now the textfield does not recognize pink or red as being the correct answer. When I run the simulator and type in Red in the textfield, it says Incorrect! Please try again. Same thing happens when I type in Pink. Am I missing something?

Comment: Store the lowercase strings in your array like I did: "pink", not "Pink"